# User is unable to install android app at the same time on play store. How to resolve this?

Tags: android, firebase, google-play, google-play-console

Hello all I've three play store app with the package name

com.gohiggs.cboxapp https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.gohiggs.cboxapp

com.gohiggs.luvduv https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.gohiggs.luvduv

com.gohiggs.yostatus https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.gohiggs.yostatus

but I'm unable to install three of the app at the same time. it is showing this following error.

[image: Playstore error]

Comment: You are most probably using same firebase project is for all three apps.

Comment: yes @SHS I'm using same project

Comment: I do not recollect currently, but the google services json should be different for each apps. ( may be different projects )

Answer (score 1):

it happen only when your apps are using same File Provider path. 
try to change name tag of your file provider path

```
<paths>
<external-path name="use_uniq_name_here" path="." />
<root-path path="/" name="use_uniq_name_here" />
```

Answer (score 0):

Whenever we want to access files from device SD-card, we need to add 'provider' in android manifest of app as following.

```
    <provider
        android:name="android.support.v4.content.FileProvider"
        android:authorities="com.mywebsite.myapp.provider"
        android:exported="false"
        android:grantUriPermissions="true">
        <meta-data
            android:name="android.support.FILE_PROVIDER_PATHS"
            android:resource="@xml/file_paths_public" />
    </provider>
```

We need to give different unique names for each app. ( eg. android:authorities = "com.mywebsite.myapp.provider" ) If same name is used for multiple apps then it may only allow to install single app at a time from all these multiple apps.